# Filtering string in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a column with strings that I want to filter.

I want the column "fruits" to contain: ("apple" or "pear" or "banana") and not "ananas".

When I use the following code, everything works perfectly:

```
results_raw.where(
    (col('fruits').like('%apple%')) | 
    (col('fruits').like('%pear%')) |
    (col('fruits').like('%banana%')) |
    (col('fruits').like('%orange%')) )
```

However when I'm adding an additional condition like as follows, it doesn't work anymore:

```
results_raw.where(
    (col('fruits').like('%apple%')) | 
    (col('fruits').like('%pear%')) |
    (col('fruits').like('%banana%')) |
    (col('fruits').like('%orange%')) &
    (col('fruits') != ('%ananas%')) )
```

It may seem a basic question but I have been struggling with the "and not" case.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: So, `bananas`... Should that be selected  or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can negate with `~` (and you need to keep your brackets in order):

```
(cond1 | cond2 | cond3 | cond4) & ~col('fruits').like('%ananas%')
```

Comment: @user3577165: consider accepting the answer as it's working for you.